# Bootstrap HTML - Where do I insert the images?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am asking an question, regarding to this bootstrap template:
https://startbootstrap.com/previews/landing-page/

As you can see, there are 3 sections saying "Fully Responsive, Bootstrap4 Ready and Easy to use"

My question is just, how do I insert an image into these sections?

I probably have to insert the image into this line of code:

```
 <div class="features-icons-icon d-flex">
```

I already tried it by simply replacing the svg class with

```
style="background-image: url('img/hello.jpg');"></div>
```

However, the image wont appear.

Comment: use a `img` tag...

Answer (score 0):

Just try use `<img>` instead of styling

Comment: Yeah I tried `  <img src="img/hello.jpg">`and the image also appears now, however it is streched out and does not fit  - I just want to replace the appearing icon with the image that I got

Comment: You can add `showcase-img` class if it doesn't fit. Should do the work

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you want to insert an image, use the image tag.

```
<img src="img/hello.jpg">
```

The three 'images', a computer screen, stack, and a checkmark, aren't actually images, they are icons, represented by the i tag.

To style in the similar way as the icons (height, width) you will have to adjust the css to the way you see fit.

```
<img src="img/hello.jpg" style="height: 100px; width: 100px">
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code, apparently, but your question is quite generic. So here are a few steps to consider:

**1. Make sure you are using the right path to your image.**
As stupid this tip may sound, there are some things to observe regarding paths in HTML.
Check your browser dev tools with inspect element in order to see if that image has been correctly loaded.
For better reference, check: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

**2. Set a height and width for your div.**
Divs are block elements. That means that usually they will assume the size of elements inside it. If there is nothing inside that Div element, the block element width and height will be 0. So long you don't intend to insert anything inside, you should add the properties of width and height to your div as well, in order to ensure the element itself
doesn't depend on other elements to have height or width.
Inside your css file, make sure to have something like:

```
.features-icons-icon{
    background-image: url('img/hello.jpg');
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

For better reference at block elements, please check: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

**3. Make sure that, if you are using responsive width and height, the element that nests the div has width and height.**
As the div element is nested inside another element, the element that nests that empty div, which uses relative css units, should have length and width on its own.
For better reference at relative units, please check:
[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

I might have missed something, but those tips should suffice. My personal hunch is that you should check step 2, that you might have overlooked.